# Grails app not running in Debug mode in intellij idea

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spring-security

Problem while running Grails application in debug mode.

When I run my grails app as run-app it works fine and give me login page and when I entered `userid` and `password` and click on login button it simply logged me in system and application runs fine.

In debug mode when I send a request to a controller that does not require Spring authentication (logged in our system) debug work fine for that controller.

The problem is when I run the app in debug mode and sending an unauthenticated request to a secured controller action. It start the server and give me a login page (landing page). But when I entered `userId` and `password` and click on login button. It start processing (waiting for localhost) and I waited so long but I din't logged in my system.

I am running app with following configuration:

```
Grails : 2.0.3
Java : JDK 1.7
Spring-security-core : 1.2.7.3
IntelliJ IDEA :13.0.2
```

Comment: Can you provide any log output?

Comment: there is nothing in log. it seems springsecurity not allowing me to logged in when i run app on debug mode.

Comment: set your root looger to Trace or Debug level